# Is scripting still possible after image have been resized with PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing, security

I want to have an upload system on my website, where users can only upload images.
These images will be resized by PHP directly on upload, so the original image will not be stored.
Do I still have to worry about scripts like php, etc. executing from malicious images?

Comment: If you're only storing a resized image than you don't have to worry about malicious code because YOU generated the image (assuming you're using something like imagejpeg() and not a file-system function like copy).

Comment: Upfront: Which program do you use to resize the images? Something like GD or ImageMagick? In general you don't have to worry about the resized images, since they are completely new - your program just reads the data (pixel and color information) of the uploaded images into an internal buffer, executes all your actions and creates a completely new file from the buffer.

Comment: just check that user uploaded image: mime types, filter in upload form, etc. Because resize functions will fail with fatal error with wrong file type.

Comment: Just PHP's default createimagefrom???(), etc. functions, so no library, but I might consider using one if the advantages for me weigh up to the filesize ;)

Comment: @MikeB That was what I was thinking, so that's great. Thanks!

Comment: The mime type is user-defined. An attacker will not lie in this point and reveal that his upload is NOT an image.

Comment: @PavelNovitsky But even when these match, images can still contain executable code which will not produce a fatal error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have the following attack vectors to consider:

1. The uploaded image will be stored for a certain time on the server and could be used for evil if there are bugs in your application.
2. Any byte trash uploaded as the image might trigger bugs in your resize code that reads the uploaded image, so it is important to stay up to date with this software or library.

Apart from that, the generated image should be considered safe.

Update:

Uploading images with PHP always results in a temporary file being created somewhere, possibly in an unknown "temporary file directory" location that everyone else on a shared host is also using. This file has a file name and possibly the malicious content. Although the filename is randomly generated, an attacker might be able to guess it and try to use it. On the other hand, you cannot protect yourself from this built-in php mechanism other than not to use unsafe include/require statements, because usually an attack requires a) getting evil code on your server and b) executing it.

Steps against it seem obvious: Configure a dedicated upload directory for your php. Secure it against code execution on the filesystem level by applying appropriate rights and restrictions. Don't mess with the random name generation. Keep this directory out of DOCUMENT_ROOT.

The second attack might be that an attacker tricks your code into reading a non-uploaded nonpublic file with the intent to reveal it's content. So it is a very good idea to check if the filename inside $_FILES really [is an uploaded file](http://de3.php.net/is-uploaded-file) before proceeding.

Comment: 1.The uploaded image will be stored for a certain time on the server and... - Could you explain how a malicious user could access these temporary images?